# Is there a way to have a screen with snap points(presentation: "modal") in react native navigation?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-native-modal

I want to have a scrollable (with snap points) react native navigation stack screen(presentation: "modal") in my app. I don't want anything like "react-native-modal" library or official Modal from react native library. I want an actual screen with modal behaviour and I can achieve that with presentation: "modal" property but I want it to have snap points. Perfect example would be the iOS fitness app.
[So this is the screen when you initially press upload button. As you can see it takes maybe 40% - 50% height of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC9Lo.jpg)

[If you scroll down height expands and it acts as ordinary screen with presentation: "modal"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgCy3.jpg)

[And lastly if you scroll back up it springs back to its original position and it acts as a modal(no gap at the top of the screen as in second image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O70K1.jpg)
That is the behaviour I am looking for.
If it is possible I would like to get similar behaviour on android as well.

I tried to implement that behaviour with "react-native-modal" and official Modal from "react-native" components but I want to have it as a separate screen. I also want it to feel "native like" and with these stuff it doesn't feel that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this library [react-native-simple-bottom-sheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-bottom-sheet)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for now I am already using bottom sheet but that is going to be my last option since that still doesn't have the behaviour Im looking for.

Comment: You can use sliderMinHeight and sliderMaxHeight prop.

Comment: I know but it still doesn't act as a screen and it also doesn't feel native like regular screen with presentation: "modal" does. I need seperate screen because I want to forward some props to it and then afterwards render some stuff after the screen is opened. As far as I know with any kind of modal components that is not possible. I would like the exact same behaviour as in pictures I posted.

Comment: You can make custom component and pass the props from the outside,
You can try this library [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gorhom/bottom-sheet)  
It has snapPoints also.

Comment: I know I am doing that currently, but that is not the behaviour I am looking for. It is still not separate screen, it does not feel native and doesn't matter that it is custom component it still renders at the same time as when the parent component does.